# Cant install Proxmox VE on Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

cant install Proxmax VE 7.2 on virtualbox

i Press "install Proxmax VE 7.2"
It loads And Turn into Black screen And does Nothing
How Can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue. For me increasing the memory to 8GB worked. Hope that helps.